# How to display results on jTable?

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable, resultset

I am wondering how to get the results to be displayed on jTable or txtfields?

```
private void sokaElevBetygActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
     String elPP = tfAngivetId.getText();

     if (forms.Validering.textNotEmpty(tfAngivetId)){
         try {
             hogdb.fetchRows("select elev.FORNAMN, elev.EFTERNAMN, har_betyg_i.KURSBETYG FROM ELEV, HAR_BETYG_I WHERE ELEV.ELEV_ID = " + elPP);
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "data exist");
         }
         catch(InfException ex) {  
             System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your hogdb class and what's your fetchRows method return type?

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try {
            
        hogdb = new InfDB("C:\\db\\HOGDB.FDB");        

        new StartSida(hogdb).setVisible(true);

          
        } catch (InfException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "something went wrong: " + e);
        } 

 
        }

Comment: i'm not sure if it's fetchRows or getResultSet :(

Comment: @SarahSoso, don't post code in comments. As you can see the code is not readable. Edit your question with the updated information. I suggest you search the forum using keywords like `"JTable ResultSet"` to find examples of display data from a database in a JTable.

Answer (score 0):

In this example I'm trying to show you how to populate `JTable`
from database (with connection example)..

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class JTableTest extends JFrame{

    private DefaultTableModel model;
    private JTable table;
    private final String[] colname;

    public JTableTest() {

        colname = new String[] { "NAME ", "EMAIL  " };  //table headers
        model = new DefaultTableModel(colname, 0);      //table model
        populateMyModel(model); //the following populating method
        table = new JTable(model);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        table.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        table.setBackground(new Color(245, 245, 245));
        table.setRowHeight(25);
        table.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(60, 20));

    }

    public void populateMyModel(DefaultTableModel model) {
        final String host = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        final String url = "localhost://database_name/table_name";
        final String user = "user_name";
        final String psw = "password";
        final Connection conn;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        String Name = "";
        String mail = "";

        try {
            Class.forName(host);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, psw);
            String SQL = "BLAH BLAH";
            preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            while (resultSet.next()) {

                Name = resultSet.getString("NAME");
                mail = resultSet.getString("EMAIL");

            }

            // here we populating the table model from database.
            this.model.addRow(new Object[] {Name, mail}); 

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I tried to show as much as I did and I hope this help you.